# Can .Net application with 4.5 work with SQL Server 2017

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an application with target framework as 4.5 and the SQL Server that I am connecting to is 2012 ,I need to upgrade from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2017.

Will my application need any changes ? Will still work after the upgrade?

Comment: No but .NET 4.5 is out of support for almost a decade. All versions below 4.6.2 have reached End-Of-Life (that's worse than End of Support) as all supported Windows OS versions come with 4.6.2 at least

Comment: Read the release notes for SQL 2017 and see if there are any breaking changes to any features used by your application / database. And then do some regression testing. That's really the only way to answer the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade of SQL server tends to be problem free.

In fact such upgrades have never caused a problem for me.

So, I'm comfortable stating that such a upgrade should be problem free, and very rare if any code changes are required.
It's possible you have used some SQL features that been deprecated, but even that's rare.

So just upgrade, test some of the features and you should be good to go.

So, based on experience, such upgrades tend to be problem free. So this type of upgrade in general is quite seamless, and say upgrade of the web server would be something of greater concern and potential issues.